# In PrimeNG p-table 'Column Resize' with Frozen Columns

Tags: angular5, primeng, primeng-turbotable

When using *Column Resize* **without frozen** column, it changes width of column which we stretching, but when we **added frozen columns** and if try to stretch first unfrozen column, it is expanding width of **frozen column**.Using **Angular 5.2.0 and PrimeNG 5.2.0**.

Code structure with requirement as shown below:

(Extra info about table)
in below code::

1st col is of Header Label

2nd for search

1st col is of checkbox for selecting row

tried with updated PrimeNG 5.2.7. adding [pResizableColumnDisabled]="true" to frozen columns

related links:
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/scroll

```
<p-table id="tid"
         [(selection)]="selectedRows"
         [value]="totalRows" 
         [columns]="cols"
         [rows]="500"
         [paginator]="true"
         [pageLinks]="pageLinkSize"
         (onPage)="paginate($event)"
         [scrollable]="true" 
         scrollHeight="420px" 
         [alwaysShowPaginator]="true"
         [frozenColumns]="frozenCols"
         frozenWidth="{{frozenWidth}}px" 
         [resizableColumns]="true"
         columnResizeMode="expand"
         (onFilter)="onFilter($event)"
         autoLayout="true"
         #dt
         >
    <ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
        <colgroup>
            <col>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let col of columns">
                <col>
            </ng-container>
        </colgroup>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr id="headerRow" >
            <th id="checkBoxCol" > <!-- this row for checkbox -->  
                <p-tableHeaderCheckbox ></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
            </th>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let frozenColumn of frozenColumns" pTemplate="frozenheader" > 
                <th  [pSortableColumn]="frozenColumn.field" 
                     [style.width.px]="frozenColumn.colWidth"
                    > <!--  specified width for each col using style.width.px--> 
<!--Tried with PrimeNG 5.2.7 pResizableColumn 
                    [pResizableColumnDisabled]="true" -->
                    <span>{{frozenColumn.header}}</span> <p-sortIcon [field]="frozenColumn.field"></p-sortIcon>

                </th>
            </ng-container> 
            <ng-container *ngFor="let col of columns">
                <th [pSortableColumn]="col.field"
                     [style.width.px]="col.colWidth"
                     pResizableColumn>
                    <span>{{col.header}}</span> <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>
               </th> 
            </ng-container> 
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <th id="checkBoxCol" ></th>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let col of columns">
                <th pResizableColumn><!-- row for search input-->
                    <input pInputText
                           type="text"
                           (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, col.filterMatchMode)"
                           #gridFilerInput>                     </th>
            </ng-container>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns" let-index="rowIndex">

        <tr id="tableBody" [pSelectableRow]="rowData" > 
            <td id="checkBoxCol"><!-- style="width: 30px" -->
                <p-tableCheckbox [value]="rowData"></p-tableCheckbox>
            </td>
           <ng-container class="frozenColBody" *ngFor="let frozenColumn of frozenColumns" pTemplate="frozenbody"> 
                <td [style.width.px]="frozenColumn.colWidth"
                    >
                     {{rowData[frozenColumn.field]}}
                </td>
            </ng-container>  
            <ng-container class="unFrozenColBody" *ngFor="let col of columns" >
                <td [style.width.px]="col.colWidth"
                    class="ui-resizable-column" >
                     {{rowData[col.field]}}
                </td>
            </ng-container>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>

</p-table>
```

Comment: Bad tagging. Read the info about the tags. Do you use them all?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?